# Select the nth most recent row from multiple groups

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Using Oracle 12c, I have a table `table1` like this:

```
ID    DATA1    DATA2    LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP
1       1        2            time_stamp1
2       1        2            time_stamp2
3       2        1            time_stamp3
4       2        2            time_stamp4
5       1        2            time_stamp5
6       1        1            time_stamp6
7       2        2            time_stamp7
8       1        1            time_stamp8
9       2        1            time_stamp9
10      1        2            time_stamp10
```

The `DATA1` AND `DATA2` only has four posssible pairs:

`1,1` `1,2` `2,1` `2,2`

**How to get the IDs of every pair, if ordered by `LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP`, which are the nth most recent records?**

For example, if `LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP` is already ordered in descending order, then for the most recent, the IDs of four pairs would be `1,3,4,6`. For the second most recent, it would be `2,7,8,9`.

---

#### Solution

Thanks to [@kordirko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2568341/kordirko). This is the SQL I end up using

```
SELECT ID
FROM (
SELECT t.*,
       row_number() 
       over (partition by data1, data2 
             ORDER BY last_updated_timestamp DESC) as rn
       FROM table1 t
)
WHERE rn = n --n means the nth most recent, starts from 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT ID, DATA1, DATA2, LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP,
       rn -- this is a number of pair: 1-first most recent, 2-second most recent etc.
FROM (
   SELECT t.*,
          row_number() 
             over (partition by data1, data2 
                   ORDER BY last_updated_timestamp DESC) as Rn
)
WHERE rn <= 5 -- where 5 is a limit ==> you will get at most 5 most recent records for each pair
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only one row returned, then you can use `fetch first` clause (technically called a "row-limiting clause").  For instance, to get the fifth row for (1, 1):

```
select t.*
from table1 t
where data1 = 1 and data2 = 1
order by last_update_timestamp desc
offset 4
fetch next 1 row only;
```

Note that `offset` is "4" not "5" in this case because four rows are skipped to get to the fifth row.  For performance, an index on `(data1, data2, last_upate_timestamp)` is recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think what I want to ask is actually to get nth most recent from every pair. Question has been updated.